# Curl of magnetic field (Ampère's law)

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

I'm a little bit confused about Ampère's law concerning the curl of a magnetic field:
$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \mu_{0}\vec{J}(\vec{r})$$

with $\vec{J}(\vec{r})$ the volume current density in $\vec{r}$. How can this be true in the case of an infinite straight wire carrying a steady current $\vec{I}$ ? Clearly the magnetic field has nonzero curl everywhere but the volume current density is zero everywhere because there is no charge density anywhere except maybe along the line. Am I misunderstanding the notion of volume current density ?

Comment: You can’t have a current without having a current density. You can have a current density without having a charge density. For example, if you have positive charge density (say, protons) sitting still, and an equal negative charge density of electrons, with some of them movng, then you have no net charge density but you do have a current density. The wire $does$ have a current density,

Comment: Basically the density thing changes depending on the kind of thing it is. Here it should be current per area density thing. And we say that the wire has some cross ectional area

Answer (score 2):

You can’t have a current without having a current density. But you *can* have a current density without having a charge density.

For example, if you have positive charge density (say, protons) sitting still, and an equal negative charge density of electrons, with some of them moving, then you have no net charge density but you do have a current density.

So... the wire *does* have a current density.

Comment: So you are saying that the empty space around the wire (with no charge density) is equivalent with an equal but opposite ammount of 2 charge densities with one of them moving ? If this is true, is it then also okay to say that empty space in general without any wires is the same as an equal but opposite ammount of 2 charge densities (with one of them possibly moving) ? I think i'm confusing myself...

Comment: I’m talking about the wire, which is made of protons, neutrons, and electrons, not the empty space around the wire! There is a current density *in the wire*. There is *no* current density in the space outside. If you idealize the wire as infinitely thin, then the current density involves a delta function. It’s easier to imagine a finite-diameter wire.

Comment: If there is no current density in the space outside, then the curl must be zero there according to Ampère's law. But the curl is clearly non zero in the space outside if you look at the field lines.

Comment: No, you don’t understand curl. It doesn’t mean “curving field lines”. Just because field lines form circles around a wire, it doesn’t mean that the mathematical curl outside is nonzero. Try computing the field outside the wire, and compute its curl.

Comment: Look up the expression for the curl in cylindrical coordinates $(\rho, \phi, z)$. Then compute it for $\vec{B}\sim\hat{\phi}/\rho$. It will be zero.

Comment: It’s kind of similar to divergence. When you have a point charge, the electric field is radially outward. The field lines “diverge” from each other everywhere. But the mathematical *divergence* of the field is nonzero only at the charge.

Comment: @einsteinwasmyfather I struggled with a similar concept as you are right now, but with divergence. The divergence of the electric field around a point particle is zero everywhere except at the position of the particle. Likewise, in this case, the curl of the magnetic field is exactly zero everywhere except on the wire.

Comment: The curl is a measure of local rotation. As a way of observing its effects, one might place a small pinwheel at the location of $\vec{r}$ and observe it's motion from the force exerted by the field. If it begins to rotate, there is a non-zero curl at that point. The magnetic field everywhere not on the wire is locally a straight line. It is only exactly at the wire that a very small pinwheel will locally rotate from the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

The actual curl is

$$\nabla \times\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \mu_0\vec{J}(\vec{r})+\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \vec{E}(\vec{r})}{\partial t}$$

However, commenters above have answered the question as to why your example is incorrect. There is a current density on the straight wire. You cannot have a current without a current density.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are asking about Ampere's law in magnetostatics, and is definitely a valid question.

Second, you're right. Both sides of this equation are volume-based quantities. But when converting to integral form by using Stokes' theorem, you have to pick a contour and the surface enclosed by the contour. If you pick the contour as a circle rotating around the wire, then you arrive at the integral form the Ampere's law. The volume current density though may point in any direction, but only the portion that goes through the surface ends up contribute.

You are right, the curl of the magnetic field seems like zero everywhere for a wire current (when you directly calculate the differential value), but it is not zero at the wire location. You can apply Stokes theorem in cylindrical coordinate for a small circle around the wire to find it out. It is equal to I/S, where S is the area. When you make S infinitely small, it is approaching infinity. Therefore, the curl for the H field of an infinite wire at the wire location is a delta function along the wire. It is zero everywhere, except for when collocated with the wire.